# How to write conditions in Jenkinsfile, if repo already cloned, skipped that stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Or, is it possible to add manual stage, yes/no, that while the pipeline is running, I can decide to jump a current stage?

Something similar to this, but even if I choose skip, it continues to run.

```
    stage('Approval') {
        input {
           message 'Should we continue?'
         }
      steps {
         echo 'Deploying'

         }
      }
```

Comment: Hi, have you installed "Pipeline: Input step" plugin?

Comment: For conditions there's `when` directive but in your case it's probably easier to do this check (that repo is already cloned) from within build script.

Comment: Yes, I installed Pipeline plugin.  Then, how the script should be looks like?